Should Roof Sheathing Attach to Ridge Joint?
Something looks funny to me. My home inspector says that the sheathing should be attached to the ridge joint but someone else is saying that there should be more of a gap between sheathing and the ridge joint. Is there a problem here or am I imagining things? TIA!



Yes, do you have a ridge vent?  If not, I would expect the sheathing to meet at the peak.  If yes, obviously there should be a gap.

Thank you for taking the time to respond. I have updated the post to show an image of the entire roof. It looks to me like I have off ridge vents instead of a ridge vent.  Should there be such a signifigent gap between the sheathing peak and the ridge joint? If not, is there a solution, aside from removing those sheets from the top and then reattaching them?

Ridge vents are commonly installed over a simple slot which is either left at construction or cut in later. It's not important that the level edges of the sheathing be supported. What I see in your case is as expected, and your inspector is mistaken.
It's also uncommon to even have a ridge board anymore. Most roof systems comprise sets of engineered trusses. They will not be connected at the peak in many cases except by the sheathing, which may have a gap for venting or may simply come (close) together. There will rarely be edge support of any kind.
